# Proper way to write 'one but not both' situation?

Tags: c, expression

This question is really arbitrary so I'll try to explain it as best as I can. I'm looping through two strings of unknown size.

```
bool check(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    char special = 'k';

    for (int size_t i = 0;              ; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

I want the terminating condition of the for loop to be the following:

Leave the loop only if either str1[i] == special OR str2[i] == special, **but not both**.

For this question, ignore the fact that I might segment fault since I know neither the size nor am I checking for `0x00`.

I know how to write this but it's always really messy and involves using ternary conditional operators. What is a better way to write it?

Comment: Keyword: **exclusive-OR**.

Comment: (str1[i] - special ) ^ (str2[i] - special)

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene: Please do not answer questions in the comments section.

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene: This does not work in general. E.g. with the values 1,2,3, you can get (2-1) ^ (3-1) == 1 ^ 2 == 3 == nonzero == true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) operator written as `^` use it like you would and `&&` or or `||`. It is true only if one but not both arguments are true.

Comment: That's right. `(str1[i] == special) ^ (str2[i] == special)`. Simples. The OP's requirement is literally the definition of XOR :) Please expand your answer a bit though...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How the hell do I get into my 4th year of computer science and not remember this one? I do however use the bitwise operator `&` all the time! I should have learned more in my discrete math class. Oh well.. thank you!

Comment: @Hatefiend : it is much harder to learn much C purely from courses as the problems are very artificial and the style relies on what your tutors like. I expect after some experience with code in the wild it will become second nature. Good luck and I am happy to have been a help.

Comment: @Vality Though those bitwise operators are present in (almost) every language I've seen. I remember learning most of them in introduction to Java :) They are just used seldom so I suppose they are somewhat easy to forget.

Comment: @Hatefiend yeah, that is true, it is not that bitwise ops are not implemented, just they are rarely enough used one does not become used to them. But on the occasion they are appropriate they are often a very elegant answer. Also, as a shameless plug, if this helped you solve the issue please hit the accept button so others viewing the question know this worked for you :)

Comment: Sorry I meant to hit accept right when I posted my first reply but the 10 minute timer was still going so I couldn't. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `(str1[i] == special) != (str2[i] == special)`, as suggested [here](http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/logical-xor.html).

This works because in `c`, `==` can only return one of the `int` values `0` or `1` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6swh93dx.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Oops: now see OP said "For this question, ignore the fact that I might segment fault since I know neither the size nor am I checking for 0x00."

So my concern below is moot.  Leaving as a reference.

---

Since code is working with *strings*, the loop must terminate on 3 conditions:

1. Leave the loop if either `(str1[i] == special) != (str2[i] == special)`, but not both.
2. `str1[i] == 0`.
3. `str2[i] == 0`.

Code code be

```
for (int size_t i = 0; 
     ((str1[i] == special) != (str2[i] == special)) && str1[i] && str2[i]); 
     i++) {
  ...
}
```

Perhaps a simplification could be had.